# Do covalent networks experience dipole-dipole forces?

Tags: molecules, covalent-compounds

After my research, I have learnt that dipole-dipole forces only exist between polar covalent molecules.

I am aware that covalent networks are not molecules, thus they obviously cannot be classified as a polar covalent molecule. However, covalent networks such as SiC are overall rendered polar, and I have read that SiC does experience dipole-dipole forces between its compounds.

I don’t understand how SiC can experience dipole-dipole forces as it is not made up of molecules - or am I mistaken here? Are covalent networks made up of molecules?

I would be grateful for any help in clearing up my confusion on the overarching question of: Do covalent networks such as SiC experience dipole-dipole forces, and if so, does this force exist between silicon carbide *molecules*?

Comment: I object to this very question. Silicon carbide molecules are not a thing, except maybe in the gas phase which itself is not much of a thing, and the forces in a covalent network do not matter, because the network is going to stay regardless of those.

Answer (score 3):

Dipole - dipole forces occur any time where there are 2 or more pairs of dislocated but connected charges. Be aware they are nothing else but ordinary coulombic forces, just reorganized in their evaluation, as their connection limits the degrees of their freedom.

Therefore, if there is some covalent chain

$$\ce{\bond{-}A^{(+)}-B^{(-)}-A^{(+)}-B^{(-)}\bond{-}}$$

then the sequence of A and B atoms with partial alternating charges can be formally evaluated as the sequence of connected and oriented dipoles
$$\ce{A^{(+)}-B^{(-)}},$$

regardless of if such an approach is useful.

The same applies for dipoles in different molecules or different branches of the same molecule (e.g. in proteins).